# Turning array values back into variables

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have made an array of userid's that prints out like this

```
Array ( [0] => 8,7 [1] => 8,6 [2] => 6 [3] =>8,7 [4] =>6,8 [5] => 6,9).
```

I'm trying to figure out how to turn these values within the array back into a variable that I can use like $userid. So for example turn **[4] =>6,8** into $userid =6 and $userid=8.

Comment: If it's always the same variable you just overwrite it every time! I think you want: [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) Have you tried something? How do you want to use these variables later?

Comment: @Rizier123 is right. How will you be using `$userid`? If it is in a loop it would be OK.

Comment: I think you want to use a loop, so do `$users = $arr[$item_I_want]; foreach ($users as $user_id) // Do thing with every $user_id`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm still getting my head around the answers and trying some stuff out. Once I have the user_id's back into variables I will use them to pull further information from mysql database (name, email etc...). I'm only interested in getting the variables for one key at a time( some of the keys have two values or userid's within them).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = array( [0] => 8,7 [1] => 8,6 [2] => 6 [3] =>8,7 [4] =>6,8 [5] => 6,9);

$explode_ids = explode(',', $ids[0]);

$id1 = $explode_ids[0];
$id2 = $explode_ids[1];
```

If you want this for every value of the array in loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {

$explode_ids = explode(',', $ids[$i]);

$id1 = $explode_ids[0];
$id2 = $explode_ids[1];

}
```

Comment: 1. No every element has 2 values so you may access an undefined offset 2. You overwrite the variable each loop

Comment: Well, it's easy to verificate that, and obviously I overwrite, he can di the operations he needs in the loop, but I don't know exactly what he's looking for, so that's just an idea.

Comment: *but I don't know exactly what he's looking for* But you can answer the question so somehow you have to know what he wants?!

Comment: Yeah, in fact... are you serious? I mean, he can get the IDs he's looking for, and so taht's a first help. If he needs all the IDs in one time at the nd of the script that will be another thing, and he could easily edit that script.

Answer (score 0):

Do u want sth like that?

```
$array_with_ids = [];
$len = count($array);

for ($a = 0; $a < $len; $a++)
{
    $array2 = explode(',', $array[$a]);
    $len2 = count($array2);

    for ($b = 0; $b < $len2; $b++)
    {
        $array_with_ids[] = $array2[$b];
    }
}
```

And, finally, u have all ids in `$array_with_ids` array, so u can call them by `$array_with_ids[0]`, `$array_with_ids[1]`...